# Find the value when $n$ goes to infinity of this integral :

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I need to find the value of this integral when $n$ goes to infinity:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^n}\,dx$$

It should have the same value regardless if it's a Lebesgue and Riemann integral, yet I've been stuck because the function does not converge simply in $[0,1]$, so I can't use the theorem of dominated convergence. I thought about using the TDC on $]1,+\infty[$, and use a majoration on $[0,1]$ but I can't find a majoration that would make the thing go to 0.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do we have to compute a limit for $n\to\infty$ from the expression, or to find the value of the integral? (Please write down a clear question.) Why is dominated convergence needed if no limit is taken?

Comment: Im verry sorry I missed the most important part, yes its about the value of the limit when n goes to infinity

Comment: No problem, just edit the question...

Comment: What do you mean by saying it does not converge "simply" in $[0,1]$? $$ \int\limits_{[0,1]} \left| \frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^n} \right| \, dx \le \int\limits_{[0,1]} 1\, dx < +\infty. $$

Comment: I don't know why I didnt see this, its so obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using integration by part, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^n}\,dx\\
&=&\frac1n\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,d\sin(nx)\\
&=&\frac{1}{1+x^n}\sin(nx)\bigg|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{(1+x^n)^2}\,dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{(1+x^n)^2}\,dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Note
$$ \bigg|\frac{x^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{(1+x^n)^2}\bigg|\le g(x)$$
where
$$ g(x)=\bigg\{\begin{array}{ll}x^{n-1}\text{ if }x\in[0,1],\\\frac{1}{1+x^n}\text{ if }x>1,
\end{array} $$
and
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{(1+x^n)^2}=0 \text{ a.e.}, \int_0^\infty g(x)\;dx<\infty. $$
By the DCT, one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{1+x^n}\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}\sin(nx)}{(1+x^n)^2}\,dx=0. $$